# SelectedListIndex property of a databound ListBox cannot be set, why?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I avoided to ask this question, but the ListBox's selected index can no be set. I have read the other threads and applied the settings, but it doesn't work.

```
            <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                      Name="lstReading" Height="Auto" 
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding BookmarkSelectedIndex}">
```

In the something.xaml.cs, I am settings

```
            lstReading.DataContext = IQText;
```

Where, IQText is an `IEnumerable<dictIQ>` and includes the `BookmarkSelectedIndex` as data element. Other data elements from IQText can be used but the listindex can't be set. Could someone please let me know why?

Comment: Where is BookmarkSelectedIndex declared?

Comment: `    public class dictIQText
    {
        public bool IsLanguageOneTextAlignmentRight { get; set; }
        public bool IsLanguageTwoTextAlignmentRight { get; set; }
        public bool IsShowGrid { get; set; }
        public int BookmarkSelectedIndex { get; set; }
    } `

Comment: Everything else works, only BookmarkSelectedIndex  doesn't!

Comment: Please edit the code into your question where it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you have `BookmarkSelectedIndex` inside of `dictIQ` class? So, you have one `BookmarkSelectedIndex` per item, not per collection!

You can create separate property `BookmarkSelectedIndex` outside of `dictIQ` or create class that inherited from `ObservalbeCollection<dictIQ>` and have additional property `BookmarkSelectedIndex`:

```
public class CollectionWithIndex: ObservalbeCollection<dictIQ>
{
    public int BookmarkSelectedIndex { get; set; }
}
```

I hope you choose best solution suitable for you

Comment: Well, it's always good to make the code better and learn new techniques. Thank you. But why other properties are working and not this one? I am very new to C# as well, I tried add the code above, but it gives error on "ObservalbeCollection" that it is missing.

Comment: ObservableCollection misspelling

Comment: `why other properties are working and not this one?` - if you have one `BookmarkSelectedIndex` per item, what of them will contain selected index?

Answer (score 1):

use this code for select item at runtime...

```
List<Audio> lst = Audio.GetAudioFiles();
            Audio aufile = new Audio { FileDisplayName = "Select Audio File" };
            lst.Insert(0, aufile);
            lstPickAudio.ItemsSource = lst;
           string FileDisplayName="your condition"
            lstPickAudio.SelectedItem = lst.Where(p => p.FileName == FileDisplayName).First();
```