# How to set an Item of a ListBox to the top?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have bookmarks list, when I tap on a bookmark, another page is loaded with a listA consists of several items.

Now suppose, I tap on a bookmark, which points to the item index 100 of the listA... the other listA opens, I manage to set the SelectedIndex of the listA to 100, which is somewhere down the list is not visible.

The problem is that, the SelectedIndex is set to 100, but the list still shows the top most item, on the top.

- How can I set the item number 100 on the top, when it loads the contents?

Comment: When I check for the selectedIndex of the listA using MessageBox(), it shows, let say 100. So in my opinion the value property of SelectedIndex is set to a correct value. Or, may be I am doing something wrong. Please also read my other question related to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094524/selectedlistindex-property-of-a-databound-listbox-cannot-be-set-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works perfectly with ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset Method

Step I. Call Loaded event of the listA

```
<ListBox Name="ListA"  Loaded="HookScrollViewer">
```

Step II. Define the "HookScrollViewer" method

```
    private void HookScrollViewer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        var scrollViewer = FindChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(element);

        if (scrollViewer == null)
            return;

        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(lstA.SelectedIndex);
    }
```

Step III. Define the "FindChildOfType" method

```
    public static T FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
    {
        var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
        queue.Enqueue(root);

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = queue.Dequeue();
            for (int i = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current) - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
                var typedChild = child as T;
                if (typedChild != null)
                {
                    return typedChild;
                }
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And it works with "ListA" (Replace ListA by the name of your ListBox)

Ref: [ListBox offset in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078579/listbox-offset-in-wp7)

Answer (score 1):

ListBox is really pain in the ass (especially with complex datatemplates and virtualizing). You should use this workaround:

```
listbox.SelectedIndex = 1000; //I mean index of the last item
listbox.UpdateLayout();
listbox.SelectedIndex = 100;
listbox.UpdateLayout();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this seems to work, but still the item index is not correctly set. I can see the item 98, just on the edge of the list. Item100 is still not visible

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listBox2.TopIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: there is no such property "TopIndex"!?

Comment: In Windows Forms there is, but not in Asp.net listboxes.

Comment: I am using Window Phone 7 ListBox

Comment: This is not about WinForms or ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But If you just want to set an item on top of the listbox items then I would do..

listbox.Items.Insert(0, "something);

or

Use linq to order them

listbox.Items.OrderBy("something");